# .normal option doesn't work in state OptionSet for UIButton (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, swift3

I'm trying to set same `UIImage` for 2 `UIButton`'s states - Normal and Highlighted

`UIControlState` is an `OptionSet`, so it *should* work if I pass an array.

```
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: myButtonImageName), for: [.normal, .highlighted])
```

But the code above set **only** `.highlighted` state and ignores `.normal` (image set previously in IB is still displayed in `.normal` state)

But, if I run it as 2 methods it works:

```
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: myButtonImageName), for: .normal)
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: myButtonImageName), for: .highlighted)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, array literal for OptionSet represents a bitwise-ORed value.

And

```
UIControlState.normal.rawValue //->0
UIControlState.highlighted.rawValue //->1
```

Thus:

```
([.normal, .highlighted] as UIControlState).rawValue //->1
```

Taking an OptionSet type does not mean you can always pass a combined value to it. In your case your *as 2 methods* is needed.

Comment: Do you have an idea why they used 0 value for `OptionSet`? It doesn't make any sense for me... AFAIK most of option set variables are single bits, like 1,2,4,8 etc. So you can do bitwise OR. Any ideas why 0 was used for `.normal`?